# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended in query

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

Im trying to copy data from table1 to table2, but im getting ORA-00933 SQL command not properly ended in Oracle SQL, when i checked in internet i see no errors in my query, can someone help me?

```
UPDATE table1
SET    field2 = table2.field2,
       field1 = table2.field1
FROM   table2
WHERE  (table2.MSISDN = table1.MSISDN or table2.IMSI = table1.IMSI )and 
(table2.field2 != table1.field2 or table2.field1 != table1.field1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE table1
SET    field2 = table2.field2,
       field1 = table2.field1
FROM   table1
left JOIN table2 
ON (table2.MSISDN = table1.MSISDN or table2.IMSI = table1.IMSI ) 
where table2.field2 is NULL or table2.field1 is null;
```

Comment: i use similar sintax before the query that i posted, and using your query now i got
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: I have edited. Can you try again? @EdwinBossman

Comment: same result :(


ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: with the where clause as well?

Comment: Let me know once you try it again. @EdwinBossman 

I am pretty sure this should have worked

Comment: yes, also with the where clause